# PHP: magic_quotes_gpc

Tags: php, magic-quotes-gpc

According to the PHP manual:

> Sets the magic_quotes state for GPC (Get/Post/Cookie) operations. When magic_quotes are on, all ' (single-quote), " (double quote), \ (backslash) and NUL's are escaped with a backslash automatically.

But does this also apply for $_REQUEST variables?

Comment: You could verify this for yourself pretty easily.

Comment: Yes, magic quotes also work on the $_REQUEST variable.

Comment: In PHP 4, also `$_ENV` variables are escaped.

Comment: @SamDufel, I know, and I thought of it of course. But I think it is a useful question, so that other people can find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does since `$_REQUEST` is derived from content stored in `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`. However as I am sure you already noticed relying on `magic_quotes` in any way is considered bad practice which is why it was ultimately removed as of PHP 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

The $_REQUEST variables are the same as the GPC variables.

Remember that magic_quotes_gpc has been removed from PHP as of version 5.4. It's recommended that you do not rely on its presence and do not use it for new projects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `magic_quotes_gpc` affect **$_GET. $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_REQEUST**.

FYI: use of magic quotes it's evil and deprecated.
[Check the official PHP page](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) on how to disable magic_quotes_gpc runtime using a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you shouldn't be using magic quotes.

Read http://uk.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php before you go any further.